Jackson xml parser list/array of different tags
This is my test xml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>
    <Type>
        <A>
            <Name>A1</Name>
        </A>
        <A>
            <Name>A2</Name>
        </A>
        <B>
            <Value>B1</Value>
        </B>
        <B>
            <Value>B2</Value>
        </B>
        <A>
            <Name>A3</Name>
        </A>
    </Type>
</Test>

My Type, A, and B classes are defined like these;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Type {

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A")
  private List<A> a;

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "B")
  private List<B> b;
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Name")
  private String name;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Value")
  private String value;
}

When I parse it using jackson, it just stops after parsing the last A, and two Bs. For example,
Test(type=Type(a=[A(name=A3)], b=[B(value=B1), B(value=B2)]))

How can I parse the xml correctly?

Where do you getting such unusual XML? Do you have XSD for it? It must be pretty complex.

I agree that my xml is in a weird form. The xml structure is from metadata of one of the 3D CAD formats. I had to rearrange tags first using Document, then I used the jackson to parse it.

I suggest to create converter from DOM to your Dto manually. It will be way faster than try to find combination of annotations that pleases the Jackson.

Looks like it is impossible to make Json to parse it correctly.
Problem cause by the fact that such mixed tags are not idiomatic to XML. To make it valid you need quite complex XSD with inheritance and stuff.
